# How can i generate a .cs file, update the file automatic with a timer and using variables and methods in other project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, enums

I'm not sure if it's better to create a dll file or a .cs file.
But the idea is in a new project winforms to generate a cs file with some variables lists classes so i can then add the cs file to my other project ans use the classes vars and methods in run time code.

For example when i will add the cs file to my other project I will be able to type in form1 something like: `MyNewCsFile.Update();`

And this will start a timer and will update the cs file every X minutes from the other project where i generated the file.

I want to update the cs file automatic.

For example in the project where i generate the cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace tester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Win32_CodecFile> codeslist = new List<Win32_CodecFile>();
        private List<string> video = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            codeslist = GetAllCodecs();

            for (int i = 0; i < codeslist.Count; i++)
            {
                if (codeslist[i].Group == "Video")
                    video.Add(codeslist[0].Group);
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private  List<Win32_CodecFile> GetAllCodecs()
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_CodecFile");
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();

            var items = new List<Win32_CodecFile>();
            foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
            {
                var item = new Win32_CodecFile();
                item.AccessMask = (uint?)obj["AccessMask"];
                item.Archive = (bool?)obj["Archive"];
                item.Caption = (string)obj["Caption"];
                item.Compressed = (bool?)obj["Compressed"];
                item.CompressionMethod = (string)obj["CompressionMethod"];
                item.CreationClassName = (string)obj["CreationClassName"];
                item.CreationDate = (string)obj["CreationDate"];
                item.CSCreationClassName = (string)obj["CSCreationClassName"];
                item.CSName = (string)obj["CSName"];
                item.Description = (string)obj["Description"];
                item.Drive = (string)obj["Drive"];
                item.EightDotThreeFileName = (string)obj["EightDotThreeFileName"];
                item.Encrypted = (bool?)obj["Encrypted"];
                item.EncryptionMethod = (string)obj["EncryptionMethod"];
                item.Extension = (string)obj["Extension"];
                item.FileName = (string)obj["FileName"];
                item.FileSize = (ulong?)obj["FileSize"];
                item.FileType = (string)obj["FileType"];
                item.FSCreationClassName = (string)obj["FSCreationClassName"];
                item.FSName = (string)obj["FSName"];
                item.Group = (string)obj["Group"];
                item.Hidden = (bool?)obj["Hidden"];
                item.InstallDate = (string)obj["InstallDate"];
                item.InUseCount = (ulong?)obj["InUseCount"];
                item.LastAccessed = (string)obj["LastAccessed"];
                item.LastModified = (string)obj["LastModified"];
                item.Manufacturer = (string)obj["Manufacturer"];
                item.Name = (string)obj["Name"];
                item.Path = (string)obj["Path"];
                item.Readable = (bool?)obj["Readable"];
                item.Status = (string)obj["Status"];
                item.System = (bool?)obj["System"];
                item.Version = (string)obj["Version"];
                item.Writeable = (bool?)obj["Writeable"];

                items.Add(item);
            }

            return items;
        }

        public class Win32_CodecFile
        {
            public uint? AccessMask;
            public bool? Archive;
            public string Caption;
            public bool? Compressed;
            public string CompressionMethod;
            public string CreationClassName;
            public string CreationDate;
            public string CSCreationClassName;
            public string CSName;
            public string Description;
            public string Drive;
            public string EightDotThreeFileName;
            public bool? Encrypted;
            public string EncryptionMethod;
            public string Extension;
            public string FileName;
            public ulong? FileSize;
            public string FileType;
            public string FSCreationClassName;
            public string FSName;
            public string Group;
            public bool? Hidden;
            public string InstallDate;
            public ulong? InUseCount;
            public string LastAccessed;
            public string LastModified;
            public string Manufacturer;
            public string Name;
            public string Path;
            public bool? Readable;
            public string Status;
            public bool? System;
            public string Version;
            public bool? Writeable;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to write all the items in the List video to a cs file in enum type.
Then to add the cs to my other project and there i will be able to use the enum.

And also to update the cs file each X minutes and if needed to add more items to the enum.

Comment: Please share your actual requirement. Why do you need to *update the cs file each X minutes*? How can an auto-generated enum which will be recreated every x minutes be useful? Currently it seems to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The problem is that i want to create enum of all my installed codecs on my pc. I can create enum and use it but it will not be with the codecs on my pc. For that i need to run a program and fill the Lists video and audio first. But i'm looking for a way without running my program so i can make in my run time code something like: test = Codecs.Audio. then a list of all codecs so when i click the '.' after the Audio it will give me the List of codecs to select from.

Comment: That's why i wanted to make with other project something that will update the Lists video and audio with new codecs if there are any and it will update a dll or a file in my first project so i can use the codecs.

Comment: You can use **Roslyn** please search how add file how add property and what you need

Comment: You didn't say what is your requirement exactly. It's unclear what you are asking. Why should it be an enum? Why don't you use a `List<Codec>`? Or maybe you need a `T4` template? Why do you need it to be updated every x minutes?

Comment: Reza if i installed a new codec or removed one ? I want to update the Lists video/audio.  enum i wante to use it later with ffmpeg in my code so i wanted to make that i will be able to select codecs in ffmpeg command line. I thought it will be easier to select from a list of properties like. That's why i thought to use enum.

Comment: @מנימנחם So based on your last comment, I believe you don't need any design-time or run-time code generation mechanism. It's a simple case like any other applications which have some dynamic data. Compare those codecs with a list of `Products` which each product has its `Id`,`Name`, `Price`, .... And products can be dynamically added to database or removed from database. Your application can show a list of `Products` in any time you need, or can show details of a product by its key (Id or Name for example) and perform other task on products.

Comment: @מנימנחם Let me know if the case is different than what I described or you have any question about the idea. By the way, I upvoted for your question because someone has downvoted without any comment. While it doesn't deserve a downvote, but it need some more information like the answer of questions which I asked :) Also when you answer someone's comment, you can notify them by using @ character before their full name without space. After writing @ an auto complete will help you to choose name. If you don't use @ they will not see your comment unless if they come back to question by chance.

Comment: @RezaAghaei The idea you described seems logic but then i need to run my program each time to get the Lists of codecs installed on my pc ? For example in the code it self when i type: Form1. then it's showing me a lot of properties like the first one: ActiveForm or if i type: this. then i see a lot of properties like: Activate or Anchor or AutoSize.  and i don't need to run my program to see this properties. This is what i mean how i want to see and use the codecs Lists as properties.

Comment: @RezaAghaei The problem is the use might install new/uninstall a codec/s and then i will need to update somehow this properties. But the general idea is as i described above.

Comment: @מנימנחם That's not a big problem. You should not look at those codecs as properties. Just load codecs at startup of the program and put them in a `List<Codec>` or any data structure you would prefer, for example a `Dictionary<string, Codec>`. You can rely on loading codecs at startup of the program and ask the user to re-open the program if they want to reload codecs. Also you can reload codecs after a while in the program automatically or even just before showing in a list.